# Write NFC-A host-based card emulation for CPR 40.30 reader

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.4-kitkat, hce

HCE was implemented in the Android 4.4, but there is very little  information regarding how to write in an emulated card.

- I have CPR 40.30 reader
- This reader came along with some sample NFC cards. I read these cards using a NFC card reading app.

**NFC card details that are compatible with CPR 40.30**

> IC manufacturer:
>       NXP Semiconductors
>
> ```
> IC type:
> MIFARE Ultralight (MF0ICU1)
>
> -- NDEF ------------------------------
>
> NFC data set storage not present:
> Maximum NDEF storage size after format: 46 bytes
>
> -- EXTRA ------------------------------
>
>  Memory size:
> 64 bytes total memory
> * 16 pages, with 4 bytes per page
> * 48 bytes user memory (12 pages)
>
> -- TECH ------------------------------
>
>  Technologies supported:
> ISO/IEC 14443-3 (Type A) compatible
> ISO/IEC 14443-2 (Type A) compatible
>
> Android technology information:
> Tag description:
> * TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcA, android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable]
> android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable
> android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight
> android.nfc.tech.NfcA
> * Maximum transceive length: 253 bytes
> * Default maximum transceive time-out: 2000 ms
>
> Detailed protocol information:
> ID: 04:AC:91:52:CB:29:80
> ATQA: 0x4400
> SAK: 0x00
> ```

I want to write HCE code and want my Android phone to act like a card which can be read by CPR 40.30 reader. I'm assuming the HCE code should emulate a card with the above mentioned specifications, as the above NFC card can be read by the reader.

The only useful sample code I have found till now for HCE is [this](http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/07/android-host-card-emulation-with-acr122/), but it uses ISO-DEP. I want to use [NFC-A](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.html) (ISO/IEC 14443 type A) instead.

How can I write code to emulate an NFC-A card?

Referred Links:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html
- http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/07/android-host-card-emulation-with-acr122/
- [Java Card Applet and Host-based Card Emulation of Android Kitkat 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319619/java-card-applet-and-host-based-card-emulation-of-android-kitkat-4-4)
- [Android Host Card Emulation with Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570167/android-host-card-emulation-with-arduino)
- [NFC host card Emulation(HCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983446/nfc-host-card-emulationhce)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to emulate a Mifare Card in an Android application. How did you solved this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android only supports emulation of ISO/IEC 7816-4 application structures on top of ISO-DEP (ISO/IEC 14443-4). The Android API does not provide any means to access emulation of lower protocol layers.

From the [developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html):

> Specifically, Android 4.4 supports emulating cards that are based on the NFC-Forum ISO-DEP specification (based on ISO/IEC 14443-4) and process Application Protocol Data Units (APDUs) as defined in the ISO/IEC 7816-4 specification.

Note that the CPR 40.30 should support ISO-DEP too.